# How to prevent form submit when lightning:input pattern is not matched?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation

I am adding validation to a Lightning Component form and have come across an issue where a email field validates on the client-side, and if invalid, won't allow the form to submit (save).

Here's the `lightning:input` for `email`:

```
<lightning:input label="Primary Contact Email" name="primaryContactEmail" type="email" value="{!v.account.Primary_Email__c}" />
```

However, a `tel` (phone number) field will show an error message if the pattern is not matched, but won't prevent the form from submitting (saving).

Here's the `lightning:input` for `tel`:

```
<lightning:input label="Company Phone" name="companyPhone" type="tel" pattern="\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-.● ]?([0-9]{3})[-.●]?([0-9]{4})" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Please enter your number in one of these formats: (214) 555-1212 or 214-555-1212." value="{!v.account.Phone}" />
```

Is this behavior normal, and if so, what is the appropriate way to block form submission until telephone format errors are corrected?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add some code to my `lightning:button` onclick handler:

```
handleSaveForm: function(component, event, helper) {
    var allValid = component.find('field').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
    }, true);
    if (allValid) {
        var a = component.get("v.account");
        helper.saveForm(component, a);
    } else {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Error!",
            "message": "Please correct form values before saving.",
            "type" : "error"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();  
    }        
}
```

If the fields are valid, I save, otherwise, I don't and show a toast message.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to submit the form programmatically so that the input validations will be invoked. I also had 'lightning:input' and other custom components instead of the 'lightning:inputField' in the form. The below code worked for me to stop the form from submitting:

```
<!--import jQuery from static resources -->

<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                          objectApiName={!v.sObjectName}" 
                          onsubmit="{!c.handleSaveRecord}">
    <!--Needed this to make the form work-->
    <div class="slds-hide">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
        <button id="saveButton" type="submit" label="Save" />
    </div>
    <!--Put input components here-->
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Then I had a button in the controller that called 'onSave' which submits the form and thus invoking the input validations:

```
onSave: function(cmp, event, helper) {
     $('#saveButton').click();
},
```